# How to write hashtag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hashtag

I have a function like this:

```
function tweet(){
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=My text.  #myHashtag"
);
}
```

But JavasScript stops at the # sign. How to write it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `%23` which an encoded form of `#`.

If this is coming from the user, you really should use `encodeURIComponent` before putting it into the query string.

Answer (score 2):

Based on twitter doc, you can pass hashtags as `&hashtags=`

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=My+text&hashtags=bransonpickel
```

https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent

Comment: This is the right answer for Twitter specifically, but the other answers handle the more general case.

Comment: @Barmar While I do prefer general case I also think solutions should use the tools provided with what they are working with. Would be great if the selected answer had both in it, the way twitter recommends and the way you can do it if you just encode the text, assuming that will work and tweet is properly hash-tagged doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the (input) text:

```js
let input = "My text.  #myHashtag";
let baseUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=";
// window.open(baseUrl + encodeURIComponent(input));
console.log(baseUrl + encodeURIComponent(input));
```